# how to override Extjs Timefield to show custom max value

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I want to display 11:59 as the maxValue for ExtJs timefield with increment=30. I set maxValue as "23:59" but it did not work, and shows 23:30 as the maximum value. Can anyone specify which function/code to override to display 11:59 as the maximum value?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have [created a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36582862/1762224) that works in ExtJS 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try overriding 'createStore' function of 'Ext.picker.Time' to include 23:59 in the list, so that if the maxValue is set to 23:59 it will get displayed.