# override Extjs Timefield to show custom max value 23:59

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I need your help with overriding an ExtJs Time field to show one custom value, 23:59. I tried to override the `createStore` function, but my time picker still has the standard values. What could be the issue?

```
Ext.override(Ext.picker.Time, {
    createStore: function() {
        var me = this,
            utilDate = Ext.Date,
            times = [],
            min = me.absMin,
            max = me.absMax;

        while (min <= max) {
            times.push({
                disp: utilDate.dateFormat(min, me.format),
                date: min
            });
            min = utilDate.add(min, 'mi', me.increment);
        }
        var end = new Date();
        end.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
        times.push({
            disp: '23:59',
            date: end
        });

        return new Ext.data.Store({
            fields: ['disp', 'date'],
            data: times
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I guess when you look at the component's store, you will find that a filter called `time-picker-filter` is set. If you would unset that, the component would show your new record. I don't know what the filter is for, so I would advise against that.

The filter is configured and applied in the function `updateList`, and it takes the property `maxValue` or, if that one is undefined, `absMax`, as the upper limit.

So I guess you should check which values the properties `maxValue` and `absMax` contain, and if they are defined, change them to `23:59:59,999`.

Answer (score 0):

In ExtJS 6, you can override the `createStore()` method as you have already done in your earlier version.

I have create a time value of `23:59` masquerading as `24:00`.

[image]

Here is a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/awt92mob/1).

---

### Ext.picker.Time Override

```js
Ext.define('App.components.TimePicker', {
  override: 'Ext.picker.Time',

  statics: {
    createStore: function(format, increment) {
      var me = this;
      var store = me.callParent(arguments);
      var dateUtil = Ext.Date;
      var clearTime = dateUtil.clearTime;
      var initDate = this.prototype.initDate;

      if (format === 'H:i') {
        var time = clearTime(new Date(initDate[0], initDate[1], initDate[2]));
        time.setHours(23, 59);

        store.add({
          disp: '24:00',
          date: time
        });
      }

      return store;
    }
  }
});
```

### Example Usage

```js
Ext.application({
  name: 'TimeApp',
  autoCreateViewport: false,
  launch: function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
      layout: 'fit',
      items: [{
        xtype: 'form',
        title: 'Date-Field 24th Hour Example',
        bodyPadding: 12,
        items: [{
          xtype: 'timefield',
          width: 220,
          name: 'time',
          fieldLabel: 'Time',
          // ====================== // Begin custom options.
          format: 'H:i',            // Important
          emptyText : '12:00',      // Why not?
          increment: 15,            // Default value
          listConfig : {
            maxHeight: 160          // Limit rows to 5 (~32px each row)
          }
        }]
      }]
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: A related question was also asked about this: *[How to override Extjs Timefield to show custom max value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25379403/how-to-override-extjs-timefield-to-show-custom-max-value)*